# How to make a custom biblatex driver that extends biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex, citing, chicago-style

I'm trying to modify the `@online` citation style from `biblatex-chicago`  that looks like this

[image]

To something that looks like this

[image]

in particular having the URL first, the date in `[year] 年 [month] 月 [day] 日` format, and having the "accessed" word after the date (in Japanese: アクセス).

I've tried creating a custom style that inherits from `chicago-authordate`, in this case just experimenting with only printing the URL.

```latex
\ProvidesFile{ja.bbx}
\RequireBiber[2]
\RequireBibliographyStyle{chicago-authordate}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{ja}{%
  \printfield{url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthand:author}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
}
```

```latex
\ProvidesFile{ja.cbx}
\RequireCitationStyle{chicago-authordate}
```

But it doesn't build when I set the style to `style=ja` in the package declaration of `biblatex`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: url access date Japanese]

The urldate is stored as components in the fields `urlyear`, `urlmonth` and `urlday`, so they can be printed with the `\printfield` command, in whatever format is specified in their corresponding `\DeclareFieldFormat` command.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urlyear}{#1年}
```

To make things easier, store the string-text constants as bibstrings in the language file `.lbx`, call it `english-ja.lbx`. Store the term for "accessed" there as well.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{english-ja.lbx}
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \NewBibliographyString{jayear,jamonth,jaday,accessed}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit   = {english},
    jayear = {{年}{年}},
    jamonth = {{月}{月}},
    jaday = {{日}{日}},
    accessed = {{アクセス}{アクセス}},
  }
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
```

Map to the language `.lbx` file with

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-ja}
```

And now the formatting command changes to

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urlyear}{#1\bibstring{jayear}}
```

instead of being hard-coded.

Now, the core commands for printing the formatted date in parentheses

```
\addspace\mkbibparens{\printfield{urlyear}\printfield{urlmonth}\printfield{urlday}\bibstring{accessed}}
```

can be wrapped in a bibmacro for convenience, as `\newbibmacro{urldateja}`

and the bibmacro can be used inside `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` and, for the citations, inside all the `\DeclareCiteCommand`s that you will need in the `.cbx` , an example being `\footcite` in the MWE.

[image: footnote for online reference]

There are various ways you could arrange and code things inside the bibdrivers and cite commands, and do make generous use of bibmacros for cleaner code; and also the biblatex documentation will start to be close at hand from this point onward.

(In the MWE, I use a system font with kanji in it, and compiled with xelatex, but you can use whatever suits.)

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{ja.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{ja.bbx}
\RequireBiber[2]
\RequireBibliographyStyle{chicago-authordate}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-ja}


\newbibmacro{urldateja}{%
\addspace\mkbibparens{\printfield{urlyear}\printfield{urlmonth}\printfield{urlday}\bibstring{accessed}}%
}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
%  \printfield{url}%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \usebibmacro{urldateja}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthand:author}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{ja.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{ja.cbx}
\RequireCitationStyle{chicago-authordate}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{#1アクセス}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urlyear}{#1\bibstring{jayear}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urlmonth}{#1\bibstring{jamonth}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urlday}{#1\bibstring{jaday}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{%
   \usebibmacro{url}%
   \usebibmacro{urldateja}}%
   {\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\end{filecontents*}


%====================================
\begin{filecontents*}{english-ja.lbx}

  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \NewBibliographyString{jayear,jamonth,jaday,accessed}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit   = {english},
    jayear = {{年}{年}},
    jamonth = {{月}{月}},
    jaday = {{日}{日}},
    accessed = {{アクセス}{アクセス}},
  }
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
%====================================


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib} 
@online{ctan,
url = {<http://www.ctan.org>},
urldate = {2019-04-14},
}
@book{abook,
author = {An Author},
title = {A Title 本（ほん）},
date = {2019-04-14},
}
\end{filecontents*}




\documentclass[british]{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK JP}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=ja, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
x\footcite{ctan} and y\footcite{abook}

%[year] 年 [month] 月 [day] 日


%アクセス
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that dates usually get a special handling in `biblatex` and are normally not printed directly using `\printfield`. Usually `\printdate` and friends are used. They are defined in terms of other date printing commands (`\mkdaterangefull`, `\mkdaterangetrunc`, ...), which are ultimately defined via macros in the `.lbx` file (`\mkbibdatelong`, `\mkbibdateshort`).

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` is the entry type it should apply to. There is no entry type `@ja`, you want to format `@online`, so the argument must be `online`.

The following MWE works as expected for me

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ja.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{ja.bbx}
\RequireBiber[2]
\RequireBibliographyStyle{chicago-authordate}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \printfield{url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthand:author}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ja.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{ja.cbx}
\RequireCitationStyle{chicago-authordate}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=ja, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that a driver should always start with

```
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
```

and end with at least

```
  \usebibmacro{finentry}
```

if not

```
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

For the date formatting you should look into `.lbx` files, but the specific format you require will also need changes at the field format for `urldate`.